# YAML Syntax Error

Tags: yaml, bukkit

I am developing a permissions.yml file for PermissionsEx in Bukkit.

I recently encountered an error whilst validating the syntax, after exhausting all my options the error still reads "syntax error on line 130, col 18: `' "  (There is no tab spacing in this code)

The code can be found here
http://pastebin.com/KDKvd18H

If someone would be able to assist me in correcting this error it will be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Cian

Answer (score 1):

I found a tab (\t) character after one line. I fixed your YAML and at least the [online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) understands it. Here you go: http://pastebin.com/uLTs42FA. The problem was after the following part:

```
  Duke:
    prefix: '&6[&1D&2u&1k&2e&6]&8 '
    options:
         rank: '900'
    permissions:
    - essentials.heal
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
```